# problem installing magento 2 on the server

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, magento2.3.5-p2

guys I installed magento 2 on the server, and after that I removed it because it was in a different version than the one I should install. And I removed it using the command rm -rf 'project'. However when I went to install again using the command:

"composer create-project --repository = https: //repo.magento.com/ magento / project-community-edition = 2.3.5-p2".

He returned an error called "killed"

Updating dependencies (including require-dev) Killed

What can I do to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Try tto clear composer cache : composer clear-cache then run your command.

If you have composer.json or composer.lock files remove them.

Comment: I already tried the command "composer: composer clear-cache", and it didn't work) :. Where can I find composer.lock and composer.json?

Comment: Which files do you have on your project folder ?
If you believe your project folder is empty then could you try run your command in another blank folder ?

Answer (score 0):

Delete your previous Directory and run the command again

> composer create-project --repository = https: //repo.magento.com/
> magento / project-community-edition = 2.3.5-p2
> here_write_directory_name

This will install your magento perfectly